# Can I get lxml to ignore non-XML content before and after the root tag?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm trying to use lxml to process a file that may have some non-xml junk both before and after  the XML content, imagine someone captured a terminal buffer and I have something like this:

```
user@host: cat /tmp/log.xml
<log>
  <foo>...</foo>
  <bar>..
...
</bar>

</log>

user@host:
```

If I hand etree.parse the filename, it chokes on the beginning content. I can delete the first set of lines until I find a line starting with '<' and hand that to etree.parse, but then it chokes on the closing content. The opening and closing non-xml junk could be anything. I could insist on just valid XML in the files, but I'm trying to be sort of tolerant of my input. 
Any ideas?

Comment: What if someone prepended some *almost* valid XML to the start or end? Where do you draw the line?

Comment: I'm drawing the line at stuff before an obvious open root tag, and anything after the closing of that same root tag. For the situation I'm trying to solve, that'll be reasonable. I mostly expect shell commands and prompts before and after. Is your point that this is a lost cause and I should just insist on a completely valid XML doc?

Comment: I'm saying it's a lost cause and you should focus on valid XML. :-) At most you can clean everything that isn't an opening `<` from the start, everything that isn't a `>` from the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another point in the balance between convenience and correctness:

```
import re

xml = re.search(r"<(\w+).*</\1>", console_output, flags=re.DOTALL).group()
```

It expects a single root tag given in the above format.

Comment: I ended up doing this, it handles the common cases that I need to deal with, which is to extract the first thing that looks like a root tag and all of it's content.

Answer (score 0):

At most you can clean out everything that isn't a opening angle bracket from the front, and everything that isn't a closing angle bracket from the end:

```
data = data[data.find('<'):data.rfind('>')]
```

but this will fall over easily if there are any opening angle brackets at the start before the actual XML data, and any extra closing angle brackets at the end of the data. This is *not* uncommon in shell environments.

It'll be *much* easier on you if you just reject any such inputs instead.