# Process xml input with python regex

Tags: python, xml, regex

I need to clean up an xml file before I can process it. The file has junk at the start and end, and then junk in between elements. Here is an example file:

```
junkjunkjunkjunk<root>
\par junkjunkjunkjunkjunk<level1>useful info to keep</level1>
</root>
junkjunkjunkjunk
```

How do I use regex to cut out (with replace?) the start and end junk, and then the middle junk? The middle junk always starts with "\par ...".

Comment: related: [Can I get lxml to ignore non-XML content before and after the root tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15208543/4279)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following statements should remove the junk (assuming your document is stored in a variable called `xml`):

```
import re

xml = re.sub(r'.*<root>', '<root>', xml, flags=re.DOTALL)    # Remove leading junk
xml = re.sub(r'\\par[^<]*<', '<', xml)                       # Middle junk
xml = re.sub(r'</root>.*', '</root>', xml, flags=re.DOTALL)  # Trailing junk
```

Note that this assumes you know the name of the root element (and in this case, it's called `root`), otherwise you may need to adjust this slightly.

Comment: re.DOTALL flag is missing.